# How do I access "filtered" items from collection?

Tags: scala

I have a string `val trackingHeader = "k1=v1, k2=v2, k3=v3, k4=v4"` which I would like to parse and convert it to a `Map(k1 -> v1, k2 -> v2, k3 -> v3, k4 -> v4)`. Following is the code I used to do this:

```
val trackingHeadersMap = trackingHeader
  .replaceAll("\\s", "")
  .split(",")
  .map(_ split "=")
  .map { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) }
  .toMap
```

I was able to get my desired output. But, I also need to handle a malformed input case like `val trackingHeader = "k1=v1, k2=v2, k3=v3, k4="`. Notice there is no value for key `k4`. My above code will start breaking with `scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@622a1e0c (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)` so I changed it to:

```
val trackingHeadersMap = trackingHeader
  .replaceAll("\\s", "")
  .split(",")
  .map(_ split "=")
  .collect { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) }
  .toMap
```

Great now I have handle the malformed case as well by using `collect` but I would like to know what key had this issue and log it (in this example its `k4`). I tried the following and was able to get the desired result but I am not sure if its the right way to do it:

```
val badKeys = trackingHeader
    .replaceAll("\\s", "")
    .split(",")
    .map(_ split "=")
    .filterNot(_.length == 2)
```

Now I can iterate over the `badKeys` and print them out. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Going with Dima's answer here. Thanks to everyone who helped !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make the result optional, and use `flatMap` instead of `map`

```
 .flatMap {
    case Array(k, v) => Some(k -> v)
    case Array(k) => println(s"Bad entry: $k"); None
  }
```

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to add a `map` step that prints the bad key for elements matching a one-element array before the call to `collect`:

```
val trackingHeadersMap = trackingHeader
  .replaceAll("\\s", "")
  .split(",")
  .map(_ split "=")
  .map {
    case v @ Array(k) => println(s"bad key: $k"); v
    case v => v
  }.collect {
    case Array(k, v) => (k, v)
  }
  .toMap
```

A better solution (which separates side-effects from transformations) would be to use `partition` which would split this into two collections ("good" and "bad"), and handle each one separately:

```
val (good, bad) = trackingHeader
  .replaceAll("\\s", "")
  .split(",")
  .map(_ split "=")
  .partition(_.length == 2)

val trackingHeadersMap = good.map { case Array(k, v) => (k, v) }.toMap

bad.map(_(0)).foreach(k => println(s"bad key: $k"))
```